# How to manually import the pool and exit in ZFS filesystem?

Tags: 19.10, zfs

When I tried to power on the Ubuntu 19.10 I am seeing this error message:

```
Failed to import pool 'rpool'.

Command: /sbin/zpool import -c /etc/zfs/zpool.cache -N 'rpool' 
Message: cannot import 'rpool': one or more devices is currently unavailable. Error: 1

Manually import the pool and exit.
```

Few hours ago, I used my laptop normally in the CCNA class without any issue. But when I return home, I started to [see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHAQW.jpg) that message.
 Using live 19.10 bootable pen drive, I can get the [output](https://pastebin.com/qJ8Druec) of `sudo zpool import`. **But don't know how to repair and what's wrong.**

*Let me know if need more output to help.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit late replay, but I want to pitch in how I ended up solving above problem:

Apparently, my hard disk my reaching its lifespan limit. This **might not** be in your case if you haven't experience this quite often as I did. There was always something wrong with my hard disk and it keep failing.

After discussing in several other communities and hard disk test, I came to a conclusion that its time to change hard.

So I bought SSD, reflash Ubuntu. Problem solved.